# Can someone explain Javascript classic module pattern and why we would use it?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module, iife

I came across this code, which I don't understand what is going on, and then I removed the IIFE parenthesis and the console.log didn't work anymore, can someone explain what is going on,
It is called the classic module pattern.
Why we want to use it?

```
var foo = (function(){
  var publicAPI = {
    bar: function(){
      publicAPI.baz()
    },
    baz: function(){
      console.log('baz')
    }
  }
  return publicAPI
})()

foo.baz()
foo.bar()
```

removing the IIFE parenthesis the console.log doesn't work anymore.

```
var foo = function(){
  var publicAPI = {
    bar: function(){
      publicAPI.baz()
    },
    baz: function(){
      console.log('baz')
    }
  }
  return publicAPI
})
```

Thank you a lot in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Given:

```
foo = function () {}
```

`foo` is *that* function.

Given:

```
foo = function () {}();
```

`foo` is the *return value* of that function.

---

If you don't call the function, then `foo` gets a different value.

Answer (score -1):

In the IIFE you are executing the *anonymous function* inside the first pair of parenthesis `(function(){...})()` which returns an object having the `bar` and `baz` methods inside it.

so after the execution of the IIFE `foo` refers the `publicAPI` object, on which you call the `bar` and `baz` methods.

If you remove the parenthesis it just becomes a function statement which does not execute the function or returns the `publicAPI` object. So `foo` would refer to the *function object* and until you execute it `foo.bar()` or `foo.baz()` won't be available.

```js
//foo is just referring to the function object if you don't execute it
var foo = function(){
  var publicAPI = {
    bar: function(){
      publicAPI.baz()
    },
    baz: function(){
      console.log('baz')
    }
  }
  return publicAPI
}
//Execute foo to get the returned publicAPI object
foo().bar();
foo().baz();
```

So surrounding a *function definition* with a parenthesis converts it to an expression and expressions can be invoked.

```
(function{...}) --> Expression
```

You can invoke this expression and assign the returned value to variable (in your case it is foo).

```
var foo = (function{...})() --> Executed the function expression, foo contains the result of the invokation
```